# Multiple IIS applications logs configurations (multiple filebeat.prospectors)

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I'm trying to configure filebeat for IIS logs for multiple IIS application. 
IIS logs are stored in separate folders for each app.

My main goal to achieve, is to have separate set of tags fields for each application logs

So I added two prospectors configuration like that:

```
   filebeat.prospectors:

- input_type: log

  paths:
    - c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2\*.log
   document_type: iis_log

   tags: ["firstAPP", "serverName"]

fields:
  env: production

- input_type: log


  paths:
    - c:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC3\*.log
  document_type: iis_log

tags: ["secondAPP", "serverName", "API"]

fields:
  env: production
```

Unfortunately something is wrong with this configuration, because filebeat won't start.

When I use configuration for only one log path, everything works fine.

According to this example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiple-prospectors.html, configuration of multiple filebeat.prospectors is possible. But I'm not sure if I can add multiple tags.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a perfect copy of your config, the `tags` line for your second prospector just needs to be indented.